# How does this limit ove the Binomial distribution behave?

Tags: probability, statistics

My professor has given me the following exercise:

> Assume $p \in \left(0,1\right)$ and
> $n \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ and then consider $X_{n} \sim \operatorname{Bi}\left(n,p\right)$
> (Binomial Distribution with parameters $p$ and $n$).
> Then, what is the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty} P\left(X_{n} \le\frac n4\right)?$

The only attempt I have found simply states that if $n$ approaches infinity so does $\frac n4$ and therefore the probability must be $1$. However, I'm not sure that is the correct reasoning for this excersise.

EDIT: I'm actually not asked about the value for the limit, but for an approximation of $P\left(X_{n} \le\frac n4\right)$ for a large enough value of $n$.

Comment: Yes you are right, and I know that reasoning isn't correct, but using the probability function of $Bi(n,p)$ isn't helping either.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: So I have to study  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \rfloor} \binom{n}{i}p^{i}(1-p)^{n-1}$

Comment: I don't know if this is correct at all, but if I denote $Y_{i} \sim Bernouilli(p)$ I have that $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{i} \sim X_{n}$ and $\lim_{i\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{infty} Y_{i} \rightarrow p$ and so for n that is big enough I can assume that $Y_{n}$ is similar to a distribution that follows $P(Z=np) = 1$ and so if $p \leq \frac{1}{4}$ the probability is 1 and it'd be 0 in the opposite situation. I must add that I'm not actually asked about the value of the limit but for an approximation of $P(X_{n} \leq \frac{n}{4})$ for a "big" value of n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important fact to keep in mind when working with binomial distributions is that they are essentially sums of "smaller" binomial distributions, meaning for $X\sim\text{Bin}(n,p)$ and independent variables $Y_1,\dots,Y_n\sim \text{Bin}(1,p)$ we have: $$X\stackrel{d}{=}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$$
The intuition for this is that no matter if you flip one coin $n$ times and add up the number of heads or whether you flip $n$ coins once and look at the number of heads, you should expect the same distribution of the number of heads in both cases.

We can use this to rewrite the given quantity as $$\mathbb P[X_n\leq \frac{n}{4}]= \mathbb P\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\leq \frac{n}{4}\bigg]=\mathbb P\bigg[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\leq \frac{1}{4}\bigg]$$
The term $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$ should remind you of something.

Comment: Yes that is what I have been using, but now my question is: shoud I use the fact that $\overline{Y}$ converges to $p$ by LLN and then use that for my approximation, or should I instead use that $\overline{Y} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(p,\frac{p(1-p)}{n})$ by CLT?

Comment: @jaimejdtrechuelo Both are valid approaches, though i think the LLN is the simpler choice here.

Comment: That's what I thought, appreciate it